# getting this - Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs, frontend

getting this error - Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
SS- **https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/767641462179233792/1030163204707455056/unknown.png**

so confused right now, I'm just learning react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use named `import` when you import 3 components from `../Components` folder, so in `../Components/index.js` you should properly export 3 components through named `export`.

If nothing wrong there, and then explore other components in whole project tree related to lines where you use `export` statement.

Comment: tried but same error :(  this is index.js -```export { default as Footer } from './Footer';
export { default as Layout } from './Layout';
export { default as Navbar } from './Navbar';
export { default as Product } from './Product';
export { default as HeroBanner } from './HeroBanner';
export { default as FooterBanner } from './FooterBanner';
export { default as Cart } from './Cart';
```

Comment: You can export as a default only one variable (component in our case) in es modules approach. So, try snippet below and your problem should be solved.

import Footer from './Footer'
import OtherComponets from './OtherComponents'

`export {
   Footer,
   OtherComponents,
   ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have this `{Product, FooterBanner, Hero Banner} from '../components'`

This is wrong. What you are doing above is trying to import those components from a file called components.

Do this

```
Import Product from '../components/Product'
Import FooterBanner from '../components/FooterBanner'
```

Do that for all three of them, and make sure that those individual files have an `export default`, For example in `Product.jsx`, make sure the export is `export default Product`

Comment: just tried but not fixing, same error

Comment: Show the code in that is the Product.js

Comment: ``` import React from 'react'

const Product = () => {
  return (
    <div>Product</div>
  )
}

export default Product ```